# render dynamic csrf hidden input while using cache in yii2

Tags: php, caching, csrf, yii2

I have cached fragment of html including form in my view.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
  <?php echo $form->field($model, 'name'); ?>
  <?= Html::submitButton('Save') ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Problem is with CSRF validation token - it should be dynamic (not static). Is there any other / better way how to render it without disabling and enabling it again?

```
 <?php Yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = false; ?>
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
 <?php Yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = true; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?php echo $this->renderDynamic('return Yii::$app->request->csrfToken;'); ?>">
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'name'); ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save') ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

If I don't disable & enable CsrfValidation I have two tokens in html - first is from cache and the second one is dynamic.

Comment: you don't have to do this. Have you added csrf meta tags in you layout  main.php file?
and update your composer once

Comment: sure I did update everything. If I don't do that I have two hidden _csrf tokens in my form...

Comment: check your views site login.php page. they are using active form. Check how many csrf token are there. and let me know

Comment: There is only one. But it is because it's not cached - problem is only with duplicated tokens in cached blocks of code - as tokens should be dynamic there (not cached) I have to do this workaround...

Answer (score 1):

I was just running into this same issue and finally after hours of messing around with different things I came up with a way to modify it with jQuery.

```
$this->registerJs("$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=_csrf]').val('".$this->renderDynamic('return Yii::$app->request->csrfToken;')."');
});", View::POS_END);
```

And then get rid of all the extra stuff you have in there

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'name'); ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save') ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['csrf' => false]]); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="<?= $this->renderDynamic('return Yii::$app->request->csrfParam;'); ?>" value="<?= $this->renderDynamic('return Yii::$app->request->csrfToken;'); ?>" />

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```